# How to detect JavaScript from html in NodeJs and stop JS rendering

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, render, n8n

Is there a way we can detect if an html file carries Javascript ? and can we stop rendering Javascript from html, in Node JS ?

I know we can stop the html rendering all together by setting the response `content-type` from `text/html` to `text/plain`. But I'm trying to figure out some way to stop rendering the JS only.

Kindly let me know if it's even possible, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're sending the file to a browser from Node.js (you talked about changing the content type header).

To do this, you'll need to:

- Parse the file with an HTML parser (there are a few available for Node.js). Be sure it's one that normalizes input, so that (for instance), `<a href="&#106;&#97;&#118;&#97;&#115;&#99;&#114;&#105;&#112;&#116;&#58;&#99;&#111;&#100;&#101;&#72;&#101;&#114;&#101;&#40;&#41;">xxx</a>` is normalized to `<a href="javascript:codeHere()">...</a>`. (Thanks [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) for emphasizing that!)
- Using the resulting document model, remove:

  - any `script` elements
  - any `onxyz` attributes (`onclick`, `onmouseover`) on elements

    For instance, `<div onclick="..."` should be changed to `<div ...`.
  - remove any URL attributes (like `href` on `a` elements) that use the `javascript:` scheme

    For instance, `<a href="javascript:codeHere()"` should be changed to `<a href="#"` or similar (if you remove `href` entirely, that works to, but the link will no longer automatically be a tabstop etc.).

    (This is where normalization in the parser is important.)
- Serialize the resulting document model to HTML and send it to the browser

Comment: While many people are tempted to try to do this with regex, it is important to not skip the "HTML parser" step TJ mentions here (and make sure you use one that normalises input) since `href="&#106;&#97;&#118;&#97;&#115;&#99;&#114;&#105;&#112;&#116;&#58;&#99;&#111;&#100;&#101;&#72;&#101;&#114;&#101;&#40;&#41;"` is just as dangerous.